# Can’t access DOM elements created by `createDocumentFragment`

Tags: javascript, html, documentfragment

In my tutorial project, I fill the page with elements created using `DocumentFragment`. Everything happens as it should: the elements are created, drawn on the page, and displayed in the DOM. The problem is that when I try to access these elements for further work through `querySelectorAll`, I get an empty array. Why is this happening?

Using the tag `<template>`, I create and place elements in the right place for me:

```js
var renderPicture = function(photo) {
    var pictureElement = pictureTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    pictureElement.querySelector('.picture__img').src = photo.url;
    pictureElement.querySelector('.picture__stat--comments').textContent = photo.comments.length;
    pictureElement.querySelector('.picture__stat--likes').textContent = photo.likes;

    return pictureElement;
};
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < photo.length; i++) {
    fragment.appendChild(renderPicture(photo[i]));
}

picturesList.appendChild(fragment);
```

I refer to the created elements for further interaction:

```js
var pictureImg = document.querySelectorAll('.picture__img');
var pictureImg = document.querySelectorAll('.picture__link');
```

The browser ignores the elements (even though they are present in the DOM), and returns either an empty collection (with `querySelectorAll`) or `null` (if I use `querySelector`):

```
NodeList []
length
: 
0
[[Prototype]]
: 
NodeList
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Where do you place the elements into the document? Have you inspected the elements which are supposedly in the DOM? Do they have the correct class names?

Comment: Can you provide your full code?

Comment: I place the elements in a block intended for them. The class names are correct. if I fire a click event then I can catch the target on them. But I need to work with an array of all created elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `DocumentFragment` of the `<template>` before using `querySelector`. The fragment of a template is in the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content) property.

If you change this line to use the `content` property it should fix your issue.

```js
pictureTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: I changed the line as you showed and now the browser is showing an error on that line.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloneNode'). 
I use .content when I access template via querySelector
var pictureTemplate = document.querySelector('#picture').content.querySelector('.picture__link');